# Instagram Sticker Link not redirect to app

Tags: android, redirect, android-intent, webview, instagram

I have defined an intent filter of a link on my app in AndroidManifest to redirect to a specific activity. When tested by clicking the link manually or open it on the browser, it works and it redirect to my app. But, when I tested it with Stories on Instagram and using sticker link, it redirect to playstore instead. Is there anyone who ever face the same issue and any sort of way to bypass this behavior?